# Netbeans GUI and SQL issue

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, netbeans, project

//I am having a problem with Netbeans. I am trying to make the values I enter in the registration form go to the sql table when I click register yet nothing is happening. Can anyone help ?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package networking;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Registration extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Registration
     */
    public Registration() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        FullNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        EmailField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        AdressField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        PasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        Registeration = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Registration Form ");

        jLabel2.setText("Full Name");

        jLabel3.setText("Email");

        jLabel4.setText("Username");

        jLabel5.setText("Password");

        jLabel6.setText("Adresse");

        FullNameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                FullNameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        AdressField.setColumns(20);
        AdressField.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(AdressField);

        Registeration.setText("Register");
        Registeration.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RegisterationActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(105, 105, 105)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(Registeration)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(PasswordField)
                                    .addComponent(Username)
                                    .addComponent(EmailField)
                                    .addComponent(FullNameField)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(105, 282, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(FullNameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(EmailField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(Username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(PasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(Registeration)
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void RegisterationActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     try{
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/networks","root","mamaendbaba");
         Statement stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
         String Name = FullNameField.getText();
         String UserName= Username.getText();
         String Adr = AdressField.getText();
         String Pass = PasswordField.getText();
         String Emai = EmailField.getText(); 
         String excmd = "INSERT INTO networks registerd(Name, UserName, Address, Password, Email)" +
    " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
PreparedStatement statement =con.prepareStatement(excmd);
statement = (PreparedStatement) con.createStatement();

// get field values ... 
statement.setString(1, Name);
statement.setString(2, UserName);
statement.setString(3, Adr);
statement.setString(4, Pass);
statement.setString(5, Emai);
statement.executeUpdate();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }    

    }

    private void FullNameFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Registration().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTextArea AdressField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField EmailField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField FullNameField;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField PasswordField;
    private javax.swing.JButton Registeration;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Username;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

this is the ful code , it does not need any explaining , basiclu its a jform for registratio just see what can be done so u can see that i am fetching the values from the forms and trying to insert them into the tables , how ever it is not working ..

Comment: I'm assuming the actionPerformed method is actually been called. You are assuming the column order of the table, this is not a good idea, as there is no way to guareente that thins order won't change in the future. Consuming the exception in an empty try-catch is never good practice

Comment: Is this [tag:GUI] made using [tag:Swing]?  There are some common problems with long running tasks and the EDT.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a number of single quotes from your SQL parameter variables:

```
String excmd = "INSERT INTO networks registerd VALUES ('" + Name + "','"+ UserName +"','"+ Adr +"','"+ Pass +"','"+ Emai +"')";
```

Also you are not displaying anything in your exception block which is making the code fail silently. You could add:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Better to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) here as it will not only eliminate the need to supply these  quotes, but also protect from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

---

Another potential source of of error is that there the column order may not be fully matched, e.g. there may be an *auto increment* column which would mean that you would have to specify the column names in the SQL. Also you can omit the database name E.g:

```
String excmd =
    "INSERT INTO registerd(Name, UserName, Address, Password, Email)" +
    " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = con.createPreparedStatement(excmd);
// get field values ... 
statement.setString(1, Name);
statement.setString(2, UserName);
statement.setString(3, Adr);
statement.setString(4, Pass);
statement.setString(5, Emai);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: btw is still didnt work i fixed the line and it stayed the same

Comment: Did you add `printStackTrace`? If so can you post the error from the stacktrace?

Comment: @Reimeus By the way, you missed one single quote too: after _Adr_. And +1 for PreparedStatement

Comment: You still are not displaying error in the exception block. Do those column names match those in the DB? You could test the INSERT statement with an SQL Client first to validate the syntax.

Comment: it stil did not working i have no clue why ... you guys have the code can you try it ?

Comment: We don't have access to the database @HasanChocor. Why not use the MySQL client and check that your SQL syntax is correct?